# jasypt encryption not working in spring boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jasypt

I want to do encryption for some sensitive data in application.properties file of spring boot application.

for that I have used jasypt-spring-boot-starter plugin .

also used `@EnableEncryptableProperties` tag on spring application.

I have encrypted access key for my database and written its encrypted value in the property file.

```
com.test.SharedAccessKey=ENC(vfQQ9veC1G+RV8BC0VA==)
```

also provided in property file

```
jasypt.encryptor.password=secretpassword
jasypt.encryptor.algorithm=PBEWithMD5AndDES
```

I am accessing this property in spring boot application as followes

```
@Value("${com.test.SharedAccessKey}")
public String shareAcessKey;
```

But logger.info(shareAcessKey) print as it is ENC(vfQQ9veC1G+RV8BC0VA==)

what I am missing in above , can anyone help.

Comment: which jasypt dependencies you have in your pom and what is your springboot version

Comment: <dependency>
   <groupId>com.github.ulisesbocchio</groupId>
   <artifactId>jasypt-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
   <version>2.0.0</version>
  </dependency>

Comment: <parent>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
  <version>2.0.1.RELEASE</version>
  <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
 </parent>

Answer (score 0):

Issue was resolved . I have done some configuration in my spring Configuration class @Configuration  related to property file.

as set property place  holder configure to setIgnoreUnresolvablePlaceholders

after removing above code . Jasypt password is got picked up.

Comment: Can you give me an example?

Comment: Can you please add what you have done, because i am trying to pass this on arguments -Djasypt.encryptor.password=password but it's not working fine can you help me how to pass this

Comment: Please provide more details in your solution to help others drawn to this question.